# Solve integral $\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve:

$$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} dx$$

I cann see that $D>N$ so I tried to scompose the $D$ but I get:

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-20}}{2}$$

So $\Delta < 0$ and I tried to use A and B.

$$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} dx = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2-2x+5}$$

But here I stops, on my book there is a hint, $A(2x-2)+B$.

Where should I found that $2x-2$, is it the derivate of $x^2-2x+5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the hint in your book refers to the derivative of the denominator (*see below $(*)$*). For a rational function with a quadratic denominator (and numerator of degree less than 2; if not: perform long division first) with a negative discriminant, this method always work. If the discriminant is positive, go with partial fractions.

In general, if $b^2-4ac <0$, you want to do the following: because $(\color{red}{ax^2+bx+c})' = \color{blue}{2ax+b}$, you look for numbers $A$ and $B$ so you can write and split the integral as follows:
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \int \frac{px+q}{\color{red}{ax^2+bx+c}} \,\mbox{d}x 
& \displaystyle = \int \frac{A(\color{blue}{2ax+b})+B}{\color{red}{ax^2+bx+c}} \,\mbox{d}x \\[8pt]
& \displaystyle = A \int\frac{\color{blue}{2ax+b}}{\color{red}{ax^2+bx+c}} \,\mbox{d}x + \int\frac{B}{ax^2+bx+c} \,\mbox{d}x \\[8pt]
& \displaystyle = A \ln\left( ax^2+bx+c \right) + \color{green}{ \int\frac{B}{ax^2+bx+c} \,\mbox{d}x }
\end{array}
And then continue completing the square in the denominator of the green integral, working towards $\arctan$.

---

So in this case you're looking for $A$ and $B$ such that:
$$x+1 = A(2x-2)+B$$
Clearly, $A = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and then it follows that $B=2$, so rewriting:
$$\frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} = \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\left( 2x-2 \right) + 2}{x^2-2x+5} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+5}+\frac{2}{x^2-2x+5}$$gives the integrals:
$$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+5} \,\mbox{d}x + \int \frac{2}{x^2-2x+5} \,\mbox{d}x$$
The first gives you $\ln$ of the denominator, the second can be reworked into an $\arctan$:
$$\int \frac{2}{x^2-2x+5} \,\mbox{d}x = \int \frac{2}{(x-1)^2+4} \,\mbox{d}x =\cdots$$

---

$(*)$

This is a handy step because a fraction where the numerator is the derivative of the denominator, has a very simple anti-derivative (integral): the natural logarithm of the denominator! Or, symbolically:
$$\int \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \,\mbox{d}x = \ln g(x) + C$$You can check this by taking the derivative of $\ln g(x)$, or perform a substitution $u=g(x)$ on the initial integral.

Comment: but why I can use the derivate? I didn't find anything on my book about this trick

Comment: I'll add this to the answer; see edit.

Comment: I tried to visualize the general approach, since your text book doesn't seem to explain this 'trick'.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2-2x+5} dx=\int \frac{x+1}{(x-1)^2+4} dx=\int \frac{t+1}{t^2+4} dt=\int \frac{t}{t^2+4} dt+\int \frac{1}{t^2+4} dt$$

where I have used the change of variable $t=x-1$.
The first integral on the right hand side gives ln and the second one gives arctan.

Comment: how did you find $(x-1)^2+4$?

Comment: I think the denominator immediately after the change of variable is supposed to be $t+2$.

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi It's a trick called "completing the square", and it is an important tool when dealing with second degree polynomials.

Comment: A slight typo in the third step, $dt$ instead of $dx$